# java regex selecting until string but not substring

Tags: java, regex, string

Is it possible to match everything before a certain string but ignore it if it's part of a certain other string?  For example, it should select everything before `ATA` in the following string *including* `SATA`:

```
anything SATA=1241241. anything ATA=2414121
```

The result should be  `anything SATA=1241241. anything`

But if the input string is:

```
anything  ATA1241241. anything  ATA=2414121
```

it should return `anything`

Comment: Can you make this more clear?? This is pretty confusing. What are you expecting exactly?

Comment: Is this what you want ? http://bit.ly/1f14xXU

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you want a negative look behind:

```
^.*(?<!S)ATA
```

Which will work not matter how large the unwanted substring is.

If the unwanted substring is exactly one character, you can use a (simpler) negated character class

```
^.*[^S]ATA
```

To use the regex to extract the target string, it's just one line:

```
String part = input.replaceAll("^(.*(?<!S)ATA).*", "$1");
```

This captures the target as group 1, and by adding `.*` consumes the remaining input, then replaces the match (which is the entire input) with the captured group, effectively extracting just the target.

Answer (score 0):

one way which is specific to your case can be:

```
String s = "anything SATA=1241241. anything ATA=2414121";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\WATA").matcher(s);
if (m.find()){
    System.out.println(s.substring(0, m.start()));
}else {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

here it find all *ATA where * is not a word character

Answer (score 0):

In `replaceAll()` this simple regex will do `(?<!S)ATA.*`. It means anything after the `ATA` and the `ATA` is not followed by a `S`(i.e. `SATA`).

```
String input = "anything SATA=1241241. anything ATA=2414121";
input = input.replaceAll("(?<!S)ATA.*", "");
```